# How to create Linq Query between a dataTable and a Sql Table

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DataTable and a SQLTable . I want to write a linq Qurty to create a result that has Information from both tables. I wrote this code. but it runs very slowly. How can I optimize it?

```
 var Result = (from DataRow row in dTable.Rows
               from obj in db.SQLTable
                where (
                       obj.Status != "Suspend" &&
                       (
                         (obj.Type.ToLower() == "a" && obj.Code == 
                          row[2].ToString()) ||

                         (obj.Type.ToLower() == "b" && 
                            obj.Code.Substring(6) == row[2].ToString()) 

                        )

                select new
                          {

                              ID = obj.ID,
                              RowNum = row[0],

                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: `ToLower() == "A"` is rather curious :) Probably a placeholder

Comment: @Caramiriel  thank you . I edited my code. But i have problem yet

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic 1) becaue questions about code optimalisarion belongs on code review. 2) unclear what you're asking

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn i want to create linq query between a datatable and sql table when i don't have a same key on both. I have some condition only. I should compare all filed in datatable with sql table and if i use loop it is very slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is 100% the correct syntax.

The idea here is that we select calculated columns to join against.  That way we're calculating the obj.Type.ToLower() and obj.Code.Substring(6) once per row (n times), rather than once per join instance (n*m times).

```
var Result = (from DataRow row in dTable.Rows
               from obj in (db.SQLTable).Select(x => new {x.Status, ObjTypeLower = x.Type.ToLower(), x.Code, ObjCodeSub = x.Code.Substring(6)})
                where (
                       obj.Status != "Suspend" &&
                       (
                         (obj.ObjTypeLower == "a" && obj.Code == 
                          row[2].ToString()) ||

                         (obj.ObjTypeLower == "b" && 
                            obj.ObjCodeSub == row[2].ToString()) 

                        )

                select new
                          {

                              ID = obj.ID,
                              RowNum = row[0],

                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: I have a datatable withe 4000 record and a sql table with 15000 record. You select special column from sql table but record number is 15000 yet and so is it effective in speed result?

Comment: well...calculating obj.Type.ToLower() 15000 times is certainly better than doing it 15000*4000 60000000...but...i guess you can try and see what happens...all depends what the interpreter does with the query

Comment: i had a typo on this line...so i changed to this - from obj in (db.SQLTable).Select(x => new {x.Status, ObjTypeLower = x.Type.ToLower(), x.Code, ObjCodeSub = x.Code.Substring(6)})

Comment: if its slow, it also might help to put the where .Status != "Suspend" before the select piece

Comment: thank you. I test it too. If i use join command can i have more speed?

Comment: Is it any faster now with the change

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var result=(from e in db.Users
        select e.UserID).Except(from m in db.Fi
                                select m.UserID).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you for answer me but I have a dataTabla and SQL Table. I want to find same record from both table and create a new result. That has information from both tables